# Cortana App Logss

Tags: c#, windows, cortana

I'm developing a Cortana App (Windows App C#) and I'm using the following commands to print debug information:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("voiceCommandName: " + voiceCommandName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("textSpoken: " + textSpoken);
```

My question is: where should I look for these texts/debug output when I use cortana to launch my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace listener is a possibility, but you can also configure Visual Studio to wait for your app to start and attach to it automatically:

- In visual studio, open up the properties page for your project.
- Navigate to the Debug options page
- Enable the "Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts" (for c# projects, it's a little different for winjs/c++ projects)
- Save the settings
- Start debugging from VS.
- Watch the Output window in VS.

VS will build, deploy, and then wait. When you use Cortana to activate your application, VS will automatically connect to your code, and can break in immediately for breakpoints, or capture output sent to the debug output, etc.

This also works for code running as part of Cortana's background task. Cortana's set up to notice if a debugger is attached and won't time out your tasks prematurely, too.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the Cortana timeout? Every time I am debugging the app if I take too long (like 5 secs) Cortana shutdown the execution of the app..

Comment: There isn't a way to manually adjust it, Cortana should be detecting that a debugger is attached and turning off the 5 second timeout, even in win10 build 10240. The only time that it didn't was back when win10 was in technical preview.

Comment: Btw, John, as a workaround, you can try to use PLMDebug from the [debugging tools for windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj680085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll need to use it on your package, see if that improves the situation. VS should be setting this itself though :S

Comment: Yeah, with VS 2015 I can debug only ~5secs and my Win 10 enterprise is not technical preview - at least i didn't see anything mentioning it. This PLMDebug tool is a command line tool right? How do I interact it with Cortana? Can you give me a link for that?

Comment: I don't have one handy. It's a command line tool you just run and give your app's app id to (not Cortana's, your app you're developing). The link in my above comment shows how it's used. Once you do, the normal suspend/resume behavior should be off for your app, and Cortana should respect that. VS should be doing this automatically however, so I'm surprised you need to.

Answer (score 3):

Usually one needs to configure a trace listener in the app config file in order to get the trace/debug output. Doesn't this work when you use cortana? Try to configure a file as trace listener - TextWriterTraceListener.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx

> To add a trace listener, edit the configuration file that corresponds to the name of your application. Within this file, you can add a listener, set its type and set its parameter, remove a listener, or clear all the listeners previously set by the application. The configuration file should be formatted like the following example.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" 
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
          initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Man I'm just starting development for windows and Cortana. Could you share the steps (or a link) of how to do that?

Comment: Here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx  
See 'Remarks' section for sample XML there.

Comment: This should be in the App.Config file right? I cannot find a way to add a App Configuration File... can you help me with that also?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio: right click on the project in Solution Explorer --> Add --> New Item --> Visual C# Items -->Application Configuration File.
Otherwise, it depends on the tools you are using. Also, you could edit the config file with any text editor, even notepad fits for that.

Comment: The config file name is exactly as the app file name but with '.config' extension. For instance, 'MyCoolApp.exe' and corresponding 'MyCoolApp.config'. The config file must be placed in the same folder with the corresponding '.exe' file.

Comment: OK Thanks! I use visual studio, however there is no option for Application Configuration File. I will create it manually.

Comment: I've an App named InsightsApp and a configuration file named InsightsApp.config with the exact content you provided. Where should the file "TextWriterOutput.log" appear? Besides, VS 2015 does not find the System.Diagnostis.Trace class.. What do you think is the problem?